# Prove that if $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $n > 1$ is not prime, then $\exists p$ prime such that $p \mid n$ and $p \leq \sqrt{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Not really sure how to do this question

this is what I have so far

$n = a \cdot b$

$(a \leq b)$

$a > \sqrt{n}$

$b > \sqrt{n}$

$ab > n$

Comment: What you have so far is not fully explained, so it's hard to follow.  What are your assumptions?  First, since $p$ is not prime, $p$ can be written as $a\cdot b$ where $a$ and $b$ are not $1$ or $p$.  Now, prove that one of $a$ and $b$ is less than $\sqrt{p}$, this looks like what you've done in your question.  Let $a$ be this element.  Finally, prove that if $p$ is a prime and $p$ divides $a$, then $p$ has the properties that you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have an assumption yet. there could be a different way then what I am thinking.

Comment: You still haven't (quite) shown that you can find a $p$ (assuming $P$ is the set of primes).

Comment: Please explain where the 5 statements that you wrote above come from.  How are they connected to each other or the problem.

Comment: My prof gave us that so i'm not sure if it is a example or connected to the problem.

Comment: As a side note, you may wish to peruse our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math here.

Comment: Depending on how you defined what a prime number is, you can prove that there is a prime dividing $n$ via a recursive application of [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem). Then if $p$ is minimal and $p \neq n$ we have $n > p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You actually proved that if $n$ is not prime, it has a divisor $a<\sqrt n$.

What remains to prove is that the *smallest* $a>1$ that divides  $n$  is prime.

Indeed, suppose $a$ has a non-trivial factorisation: write $a=bc$, $\enspace1<b,c<a$. Then $n$ has divisors $>1$ that are strictly less than $a$, so that $a$ is not the smallest divisor $>1$ of $n$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is not prime $\implies n$ has a prime factor $p\in(1,n)$.

If $p\leq\sqrt{n}$ then we're done.

If $p>\sqrt{n}$ then let $m$ denote $\frac{n}{p}$:

- $m=\frac{n}{p}\implies{mp=n}\implies\color{red}{m|n}$
- $p>\sqrt{n}\implies\frac{n}{p}<\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}\implies\color{red}{m<\sqrt{n}}$
- Let $q$ be a prime factor of $m$:

  - $\color{red}{m|n}\implies\color{blue}{q|n}$
  - $\color{red}{m<\sqrt{n}}\implies\color{blue}{q<\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score -1):

As $n$ is not prime it will at least have $2$ prime factors (may be repeated) and both of them can't be greater than $\sqrt n$, otherwise their product will exceed $n$. Hence at least of them will be $\leq \sqrt n$.

Comment: I think the proof must *not* use prime factorisation, as it is a lemma for proving the existence of such a factorisation.